# PLS as custom model in pycaret

Tags: pycaret, pls

As PyCaret allows incorporating custom models
[Link](https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/learn-pycaret/official-blog/write-and-train-custom-ml-models-using-pycaret)
I would appreciate any help in enabling PLS (partial least squares), so it can be used along with other models available in PyCaret (for comparisons, tuning, blending, predictions).

PLS is a part of sklearn, so should be compatible with PyCaret, but my naïve attempt

```
mypls = PLSRegression(n_components=5)
plsmodel = create_model(mypls)
```

returns an error... Apparently a custom class has to be defined, I am not sure how.